# Syntactic sugar for (x != null && x.y != null)

Tags: dart, syntactic-sugar

Is there a syntactic sugar to write the following code in a better way?

```
if (x != null && x.y != null) {
   ...things that use x!.y
}
```

I could write something like

```
if (x?.y != null) {
   ...things that use x!.y
}
```

but I don't think that is the same thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `x?.y != null` is mostly equivalent to `x != null && x.y != null` *except* that it doesn't *promote* `x` to non-null.

To actually promote a variable, you need to test the variable *directly*.

I'd do:

```dart
if (x != null) {  
  var y = x.y;
  if (y != null) {
    // use y
  }
}
```

in order to get promotion on *both*. Or do as @nvoght says and use `x?.y` to get the value into a variable, then promote that variable.

Comment: Why doesn't it promote x to non-nullable? In `x?.y != null`

Comment: That's just how promotion is defined. It only works for `localVariable != null` or similar direct checks on a local variable. Promotion doesn't try to infer nullability through other operations, like `x?.y != null`, which it's true can only be true if `x` is non-null. The compiler has to draw a line at some point, and "direct test of variable" was the line that was drawn.

Comment: I can't find any reason, why that line can't be pushed. This seems like we will have to put up an issue in dart sdk for this feature. Or it is not a compiler issue and I am missing some principle of the compiler that forbids it from checking this?

Comment: Nothing prevents the language from allowing promotion from an expression like this, but as the language is *currently specified*, it doesn't promote.
Changing which expressions promote is a potentially breaking change, so it's not just something the compiler can just do. 
From a language design perspective, you don't want to point to single specific expression shapes and say "that promotes too". It's better to find a general rule that applies to a slew of different expressions, because then the user only need to remember one rule. See also: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1224

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `!` if you can instead write better code:

```
final item = x?.y;
if (item != null) {
   // ...things that use item,
   // a local variable elevated to non-null inside the scope of the if,
   // no ! operator neccessary
}
```